# how to use InputBox in c++builder with multiple values

Tags: c++builder, inputbox

How can I use InputBox to make it take 3 Values. I can make it show just one value by using code:

```
String input[3];
input[0]= InputBox("paied check", "the value", "");
```

any help?

Comment: Are you trying to get 3 different values from the InputBox function? I mean, that the user can capture 3 different strings, and the function return them? If that's the case, then I'm afraid is not possible with that function. It is designed to return a single value. You could probably instruct your users to capture a comma separated list, and store that in a TStringList, but the InputBox will show only one field for the user to capture. This will be prone to errors, though. The easiest way would be to implement your own InputBox with the number of fields you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InputBox()` does not support what you are asking for.  It is designed for single-value input only.

[`InputQuery()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) supports multi-value input, but only in C++Builder XE2 and later, eg:

```
String prompt[3] = {"value 1:", "value2:", "value 3:"};
String input[3];

if( InputQuery("paied check", EXISTINGARRAY(prompt), EXISTINGARRAY(input)) )
{
    //...
}
```

Or:

```
String input[3];

if( InputQuery("paied check", OPENARRAY(String, ("value 1:", "value2:", "value 3:")), EXISTINGARRAY(input)) )
{
    //...
}
```

Notice the use of the `OPENARRAY()`/`EXISTINGARRAY()` macros (from `sysopen.h`).  They are needed because `InputQuery()` only accepts Delphi-style Open Arrays, not C-style arrays.  Open Arrays have an additional parameter (that is hidden in Delphi, but is explicit in C++) to specify the highest index (not the array count) of each array.  The macros handle that extra value for you, but they only work for static arrays (which you are using).