# how to use InputQuery with Static Info. and multiple values

Tags: c++builder

When I use this code

```
 String opra[3];
 String prompt[3] = {"operation name:","price","profit"};
  if (InputQuery("ِAdd Operation",EXISTINGARRAY(prompt),EXISTINGARRAY(opra))==true) {
//statements;
}
```

it works just fine, but when I try to add some lines before (prompt) array like

```
 if (InputQuery("ِAdd Operation",
 "patient name" + Edit1->Text
            +sLineBreak + sLineBreak
           "Date" + DateTimePicker1->Date.DateString()
            +sLineBreak + sLineBreakEXISTINGARRAY(prompt),EXISTINGARRAY(opra))==true) {
//statements;
}
```

an error occurs:

> Could not find a match for 'InputQuery(const char *,undefined,unsigned
>   int,UnicodeString *,unsigned int)'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sLineBreakEXISTINGARRAY(prompt)` is not a valid statement. You are trying to concatenate a string literal and a static array together in an invalid manner.

It is not clear exactly what you want the input box to look like, but you must pass *only* the arrays by themselves to `InputQuery()`, just like [I showed you earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884000/how-to-use-inputbox-in-cbuilder-with-multiple-values).  Only the first parameter accepts a `String`, the subsequent 4 parameters (yes 4 - `EXISTINGARRAY()` hides 2 of them for you) are array-related, just as the original code was doing.  The prompt array provides the label text for the input fields that populate the output array.  How you populate the prompt array with values is up to you.

Maybe you were trying to do something like this?

```
String opra[3];
String prompt[3] = {
    "patient name" + Edit1->Text + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + "Date" + DateTimePicker1->Date.DateString() + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + "operation name:",
    "price",
    "profit"
};

if (InputQuery("ِAdd Operation", EXISTINGARRAY(prompt), EXISTINGARRAY(opra))) {
    // use opra[] array as needed...
}
```

Or:

```
String opra[3];
String prompt[3];

prompt[0] = "patient name" + Edit1->Text + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + "Date" + DateTimePicker1->Date.DateString() + sLineBreak + sLineBreak + "operation name:";
prompt[1] = "price";
prompt[2] = "profit";

if (InputQuery("ِAdd Operation", EXISTINGARRAY(prompt), EXISTINGARRAY(opra))) {
    // use opra[] array as needed...
}
```